# How can I solve "No module named 'pyi_splash'" after using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, splash-screen

I'm trying to add a splashscreen to my app using pyinstaller by this:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --splash=Splash_screen.png --icon=Icon.ico JIGOverview.pyw
```

this opens the splashscreen but it never closes so then I try to add this code to my Python code:

```
import pyi_splash
pyi_splash.update_text('UI Loaded ...')
pyi_splash.close()
```

but I get a "No module named 'pyi_splash'" error. How do I add this module to my code?

Comment: Could you state your python version, operating system and IDE in your question and tags?

Answer (score 1):

Add the [--hidden-import](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) option:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --splash=Splash_screen.png --icon=Icon.ico --hidden-import=pyi_splash JIGOverview.pyw
```

Comment: I think the problem is running the script and not the executable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    import pyi_splash

# your code..........

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    pyi_splash.close()

#root.mainloop()
```

See: https://coderslegacy.com/python/splash-screen-for-pyinstaller-exe/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it via..

```
pip install py-splash
```

then reload your environment or ide or terminal

Comment: It is useful to include for which OS, IDE, py-version that you are making this suggestion.